# JSF / Primefaces : How to show growl faces message when executing a method?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I can show the growl message once the method is completely executed.

Is it possible to show the growl message like "Processing ...please wait a moment..." when executing a method ?

The method may take time to execute, so i may need to show a growl message to notify the user.

Or any other way to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, there a primefaces component called BlockUI which will wait for the ajax response to complete.

Using this, you can show any image as overlay when the method is being executed and you can block the user to perform any operation in that duration.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf

Comment: Hi kharkar, i tried with the blockUI, it's work for me , but the loader gif will gone after few second, it's weird. but never mind, i will solve this later. Thanks for your help.